# Coroutines: run a Deferred on a specific CoroutineContext

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm giving a try to Kotlin Coroutines inside an Android app, specifically I've imported [Kotlin Coroutine Adapter for Retrofit](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter).

Kotlin Coroutine Adapter changes Retrofit interface to return a `Deferred<T>` instead of `Call<T>`.

What I don't understand is how to launch this `Deferred` in a particular `CoroutineContext` that I want to. Consider following code:

```
    class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
        private val foo: Foo,
        @Named("ui") private val uiContext: CoroutineContext,
        @Named("network") private val networkContext: CoroutineContext
    ) : ViewModel() {

      fun performSomeJob(param: String) {
          launch(uiContext) {
            try {
              val response = foo.bar(param).await()
              myTextView.setText(response.name)
            } catch (error: Throwable) {
              Log.e(error)
            }
          }
    }
```

Where `foo.bar(param)` returns `Deferred<SomeModel>`.

This code works, but I'm not sure on what `CoroutineContext` this `foo.bar(param)` is being executed (`CommonPool`??).

How to explicitly specify, that I want `foo.bar(param)` to be executed in a `networkContext`?

```
    val response = async(networkContext) { foo.bar(param) }.await()
```

This code doesn't work, because `response` is evaluated to `Deferred<SomeModel>` instead of `SomeModel` (which I want to achieve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foo.bar()` call doesn't start another coroutine, it just wraps the native Retrofit `Call` so that its state changes get propagated to `Deferred`. Retrofit manages its own threads to perform its operations and this works just as it would without the coroutine wrapper. If you have a specific concern, you can manage it by configuring Retrofit in the usual way.

The only thing that should matter to you is that your coroutine is executing in the UI context.

Comment: But how about unit testing then? Previously (when using Rx approach) we could specify schedulers to be `trampoline()` and that resulted our test code to run on the same thread. How testable is this code now? Don't we have such abilities with coroutines?

Comment: What schedulers, exactly? Isn't it the scheduler that takes over when the network call is complete, resuming the coroutine? `trampoline()` sounds like `runBlocking()` to me.

Comment: With Rx approach there was `foo.bar().subscribeOn(bgScheduler).observeOn(uiScheduler)`. Those schedulers were injected by DI framework. For test code those dependencies were being provided as `trampoline()` scheduler which instead of changing the thread would execute the job on the calling thread. As to this example, because I cannot specify on which `CoroutineContext` to execute the background job then I cannot get sequential code execution behavior in tests, or do you claim that `runBlocking()` is the correct function to use?

Comment: `runBlocking()` will start an event loop on the calling thread, so it becomes the coroutine context. It will complete when its coroutine completes. Regardless of this, execution of Retrofit code will be sequential as long as you don't make several calls before awaiting on them.